# mysql + node.js - how to execute every or none queries?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am currently using mysql and Node.js, with *multipleStatements* I can do several queries at the same time, but if a query fails it doesn't *break* as I expected

```
app.post('/api3/stock5', function (req, res) {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
       host : conf.host,
       user : conf.user,
       password : conf.pass,
       database : conf.database,
       multipleStatements: true    //<- essential for several queries at the same time

    });
    var sql ="UPDATE  (...)"; INSERT INTO (...)";
    var query = connection.query(sql);
    query.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log("error: /api3/stock5 /n");
    console.log(sql);
  });
  query.on('result', function(result) {         
  });
  query.on('end', function(result) {

  });
      res.send('OK');
});
```

Is there any way to make sure every query was performed correctly and only in that case commit? Thanks

Comment: Look for transactions https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Node.js `mysql` library supports transactions https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#transactions